# Multiple Sign ins in Azure AD

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I've implemented SSO using SAML authentication on Asure AD in my banking application. I have a scenario where I've to let a manager/supervisor log in to approve a transaction. A regular rep would not have authority to approve, the manager would come in and physically login in (keeping the rep's session intact) and approve a transaction and then logout. Is it possible to have multiple sign ins in the same browser instance through Azure AD?

**UPDATE** - Per what I researched and mentioned by Carl as well, Azure AD does not support multiple users to login in an application in the same browser instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the same tenant, users with different roles can perform multiple logins in the same browser. Log in to the Azure portal and you can see that accounts with different roles in the upper right corner can be switched back and forth.

These identities have already validated their credentials for this session, and  have an auth token.  Switching between these accounts now will not prompt you for their passwords again.

[image]

**Update:**

Even if two accounts are in the same domain, they cannot be logged in at the same time. Currently, only two browsers can be used for two accounts in the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for the response Carl. The way I'm integrating with Azure AD is by sending a SAML request (which does not contain sign in credentials). The solution you've proposed will work if I physically go on Azure AD and try to login as a different user. But is it possible for Azure AD to prompt for sign in with a different account "of the same domain" (in your example another user of carldirectory.onmicrosoft....) when I send a SAML request with https://login.microsoftonline.com/..-9867-4c7e-a899-.../login URL, when I'm already signed in with another user of carldirectory.onmicrosoft.... domain?

Comment: I feel that you cannot log in to two accounts at the same time in the same domain. It seems that these two accounts use different browsers.

Comment: That's what I concluded as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Vinay I'm happy to serve you. I have updated some answers. If it helps you, you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

SAML SSO is a form of delegated authentication. The user is authenticated at the identity provider site (eg Azure AD) which sends a SAML assertion containing user identity information to the service provider site. The service provider trusts this information and establishes a local authentication session for the user using the information contained in the SAML assertion. SAML assertions often contain the user's email address but any user identity information may be included.

You can achieve multiple sign-ins on the same browser , Kindly check this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-use-multiple-sign-in-accounts-inside-of-azure-portal/ba-p/287507).